# Anklagen + Akk + Gen with a relative proposition

Tags: genitive, relative-pronoun

`Anklagen` requires an `Akkusativ` and a `Genitiv` for its complements, which can give a sentence such as

```
Die öffentliche Meinung klagte die führende Leute der Heuchelei an.
```

I would like to use `anklagen` now in a construction with a relative proposition. I come up with this,

```
Die öffentliche Meinung klagte die führende Leute 
insbesondere dessen an, 
dass sie behaupten, einfach Befehle auszuführen, 
während sie mit zweifelhaften Tätigkeiten 
verwickelten Unternehmen geheim aufbauen.
```

We can of course also say

```
Die öffentliche Meinung klagte die führende Leute 
ihrer Behauptung an, 
einfach Befehle auszuführen, 
während sie mit zweifelhaften Tätigkeiten 
verwickelten Unternehmen geheim aufbauen.
```

but I want to understand a possible construct with `dessen`.

Furthermore can we have the two kind of complements in the sentence, this way

```
Die öffentliche Meinung klagte die führende Leute 
der Heuchelei und insbesondere dessen an, 
dass sie behaupten, einfach Befehle auszuführen, 
während sie mit zweifelhafte Tätigkeiten 
verwickelten Unternehmen geheim aufbauen.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your use of the complements of "anklagen" is grammatically completely correct here!

So that's your answer. Compliments for that! The rest of this answer is basically uninvited advice that's not really about your question. :-)

There are some minor, more mundane glitches in your example, so I'll just add a corrected version of your last example.

> Die öffentliche Meinung klagte die führende**n** Leute
> der Heuchelei und insbesondere dessen an,
> dass sie behaupten, einfach Befehle auszuführen,
> während sie **im Geheimen** **in** zweifelhafte Tätigkeiten
> **verwickelte** Unternehmen aufbauen.

Explanations: "Geheim" works well as an adjective, but not so well as an adverb for some strange reason, thus "im Geheimen". *In* is the correct preposition in the verb "in etwas (accusative) verwickelt sein".

About the use of *anklagen* itself: This is of course an example for the grammar of *anklagen*, but I'll just mention that *anklagen* is used in a much narrower sense than the English word *to accuse* and not a good fit in the example sentences. It's really only used in a legal sense. So if it was more than just a grammar example, I would probably use "jemandem etwas vorwerfen" instead of "anklagen" in the example sentence. "Die öffentliche Meinung" isn't really able to "jemanden anklagen", only a prosecutor is, and you would also not use "jemanden einer Behauptung anklagen", it would have to be some kind of legally defined offence.

Comment: While I agree that this describes the predominant use of *anklagen*, non-legal uses are not uncommon in a formal register: *Özdogan ist damit das Gegenteil des debattenmächtigen Public Intellectual, der mit grosser moralischer Geste die Welt anklagt.* (NZZ, 17.02.2020) *Ungeachtet der Tatsache, daß die Sowjetpresse ihn immer wieder der Unterstützung der „Parteifeinde“ anklagt, bleibt er weiterhin auf seinem Posten.* (Die Zeit, 17.08.1962) *Die Künstlerin DJ Switch hat auf Twitter ein Video gepostet, in dem sie die Sicherheitskräfte anklagt: (..)* (taz, 22.10.2020)

Comment: @johnl: +1 for the comment because this was oversimplified in the answer. The examples also show that this use is quite special, The "Sowjetpresse" example is crafted to highlight the role of press in the SU as part of the system, and the other two try to stress a position of moral high ground that would be hard to attribute to "die öffentliche Meinung".